# Actualizacion de Android Studio a Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Tags: android

Buenos dias se ha actualizado el Android Studio a Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 y desde esntoces me sale este error cuando Gradle proyect sync failed:

> Caused by:
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed:

Como lo puedo solucionar.

¿Se puede desistalar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando realizas una actualización de Android Studio es recomendable invalidar el cache y reiniciar (`Invalidate Caches / Restart`), esto lo puedes realizar desde el menú principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realiza este proceso y seguramente tu Android Studio y proyecto funcionará sin problema.